# How to upload multiple files on cdn?

Tags: python, cdn

I have to upload a `webpage on cdn`. Say `test.html, test.css, image1.jpg` etc. Now I am `uploading` all these file one by one. I think which is not efficient. So, is it possible to keep all these files in `folder` and then `upload this folder` on the `cdn`? If yes, then what parameters i need to take care about that. Does zipping the folder helpful? I am using `python`.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How many files are we talking about?  What transport mechanisms are available, ftp/ssh/scp/sftp/webdav/http?  Which cdn?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload files to a CDN  simply because a CDN is a system of computers containing copies of data placed at various nodes of a network.

Basically you need to upload the data somewhere first; let's say on your webiste or blog (**www.mywebsite.com/image.jpg**) and then set up a CDN provider(e.g Amazon CloudFront) to fetch the content from your website and distribute through its network.

The CDN provider will give you a link like **blablabla.amazon.com** that you can use to deliver the content . So your image.jpg will be accessible now from **blablabla.amazon.com/image.jpg** . When users will try this link the CDN provider will route the request to its closest server to deliver the image .

```
If you need to upload multiple files , you may use AJAX.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to upload the static content of your website (not the user uploaded files) to CDN via FTP client or something similar.

To achieve bulk upload you may ZIP all such files on local machine and upload to your webserver. Unzip files on webserver and write a batch script which utlize the CDN API to send files in CDN container.

For fulture new or modified files, write another batch script to grab all new/modified files and send to CDN container via CDN API.